# При клике на содержимое 2-го модального окна оно не должно закрываться, в чем дело?

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование

Все тут

```js
var modalz = document.getElementById('myModal');
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
var spa = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

btn.onclick = function() {
 modalz.style.display = "block";
}
spa.onclick = function() {
 modalz.style.display = "none";
}

window.onclick = function (event) {
 if (event.target == modalz) {
  modalz.style.display = "none";
 }
}

var two = document.getElementById('two');
var raz = document.getElementById("raz");
var spaned = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

raz.onclick = function(e) {
 two.style.display = "block";
  e.stopPropagation();
}
spaned.onclick = function() {
 two.style.display = "none";
}

window.addEventListener ('click', function (event) {
  if (event.target != two.querySelector(".modal-content")) {
    two.style.display = "none";
  } 
});
```

```css
.modal {
 display: none;
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 1;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 overflow: auto;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
.modal-content {
 background-color: #fefefe;
 margin: 15% auto;
 padding: 20px;
 border: 1px solid #888;
 width: 80%;
}
.close {
 color: #aaa;
 float: right;
 font-size: 28px;
 font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
 <button id="myBtn">Open modal</button>
  <div id="myModal" class="modal">
   <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p> modal hui</p>
   </div>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>

  <button id="raz">Open modal</button>
  <div id="two" class="modal">
   <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p> modal 2</p>
   </div>
  </div>
  <script src="script1.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Предлагаю вот такой вариант работы с модальными окнами, он более оптимальный нежели представленный в вопросе. Комментарии его работы находятся в JS коде:

```js
//Находим все тэги button, в которых присутствует атрибут data-target
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button[data-target]');

//Находим все модальные окна
let modals = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');

//Находим все кнопки с классом close, которые лежат внутри "модального" элемента
let close = document.querySelectorAll('.modal .close')

//Здесь создаем массив, в котором будут храниться элементы, по нажатию на которые у нас не будет срабатывать событие window.click
let noPropagation = [...buttons, ...modals];

//Здесь в массиве будут лежать все элементы, по нажатию на которые у нас закрываются все модальные окна: window и кнопки close, можно добавлять и другие элементы в этот массив
let closeEvents = [window, ...close];

//Создаем функцию, которая убирает все активные модальные окна
let removeActive = () => {
modals.forEach(el => {
 el.classList.remove('active') 
})
}

//Здесь мы запрещаем срабатывания события click, при которых у нас закрываются модальные окна, подробнее читаем про event.stopPropagation()
noPropagation.forEach(item => {
item.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
 e.stopPropagation();
}) 
})

//Здесь отрабатывается закрытие модальных окон при нажатии на window и close "кнопки"
closeEvents.forEach(item => {
item.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
 removeActive()
})
})

//Здесь привязываем событие, при которых срабатывает вызов модального окна 
buttons.forEach(button => {
button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
 //Читаем атрибут data-target, который должен равняться id нашего модального окна
 let target = e.target.getAttribute('data-target')
 removeActive();
 document.getElementById(target).classList.add('active')
})
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.modal {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  display: none;
}
.modal.active {
  display: block;
}
.modal .close {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<button data-target="modal-1">Open modal 1</button>
<div id="modal-1" class="modal">
  <div class="contmod">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p> modal 1</p>
  </div>
</div>

<button data-target="modal-2">Open modal 2</button>
<div id="modal-2" class="modal">
  <div class="contmod">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p> modal 2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Потому что, как я ответил Вам в Вашем предыдущем вопросе, область действия переменных, которые Вы декларируете - глобальная, то есть вся страница.

Хм, вопрос изменился, но это ничего.

Потому что, как я ответил Вам в Вашем предыдущем вопросе,

> "Второй файл перекрывает ... `window.onclick` из первого."

Используйте `addEventListener`.

Comment: а можно пожалуйста более точную запись, видимо в моем случае я что-то не так записал и она все равно не работает.

Comment: или есть какая-то альтернатива для использования window?

Comment: window.addEventListener ('click', function (event) {
 if (event.target == two) {
  two.style.display = "none";
 }
})

Что-то не так записано :?

Comment: `if (event.target != two) {...`

Comment: не помогло https://jsfiddle.net/1aszuj8d/1/

Comment: @ErikSpichak помогло  https://jsfiddle.net/1aszuj8d/3/

Comment: Спасибо большое Игорь, за разъяснение.

Comment: Игорь, можно еще один вопрос, данным методом можно сделать N количество модальных окон ? или только на 2 модальных окна действует этот метод ? Просто я попробовал добавить 3 модальное окно, и после этого ни одно из них не стало работать ...
https://jsfiddle.net/1aszuj8d/7/

Comment: @ErikSpichak конечно, можно. важно изолировать переменные и код для каждого окна, чтобы они друг другу не мешали. если структура окон одинаковая, то это вообще можно сделать одним кодом и не повторять код для каждого окна

Comment: Простите Игорь, сам нашел в чем дело)

Comment: Игорь, тогда такой вопрос, если у нас в модальном окне есть содержимое, почему оно закрывается если мы кликаем по тому что находится в модальном окне, а не за его пределами?https://jsfiddle.net/1aszuj8d/15/

Comment: на модальные окна нужно повесить stopPropagation(), тогда "общие события", не будут передаваться на клик по модальному окну.

Comment: Needhate можно по подробней, а если не сложно, то на том же примере что указан выше, в моем случае все равно все кроме первого закрываются

Comment: @ErikSpichak `(event.target != two.querySelector(".modal-content"))` - из-за вот этого условия

Answer (score 1):

Вот исправленный пример для вашего кода:

```js
var modalz = document.getElementById('myModal');
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
var spa1 = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
var spa2 = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[1];
var mod_cont1 = document.getElementsByClassName("modal-content")[0];
var mod_cont2 = document.getElementsByClassName("modal-content")[1];
var mod_class = document.getElementsByClassName("modal")[0];
btn.onclick = function() {
        modalz.style.display = "block";
}
spa1.onclick = function() {
    modalz.style.display = "none";
}

spa2.onclick = function() {
    two.style.display = "none";
}

mod_cont1.onclick = function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
}
mod_cont2.onclick = function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
}

modalz.onclick = function(event){
    modalz.style.display = "none";
}

var two = document.getElementById('two');
var raz = document.getElementById("raz");
var spaned = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

two.onclick = function(e){
    this.style.display = 'none';
}

raz.onclick = function(e) {
    two.style.display = "block";
    e.stopPropagation();
}
```

```css
.modal {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: 15% auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
}
.close {
    color: #aaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<button id="myBtn">Open modal</button>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <p> modal hui</p>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="script.js"></script>

<button id="raz">Open modal</button>

<div id="two" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <p> modal 2</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Я взял 2 ваших класса дла `modal-content` и предотвратил всплытие события для них. и у вас была еще одна ошибка, вы не прикрепили обработчик на крестик второго модального окна. что бы закрыть окно.

Comment: спасибо за разъяснение, да ошибку тоже увидела